# Почему когда я вызываю метод повторно, пропускается nextLine и цикл не работает?

Tags: java, циклы, for, while, scanner

Задача сделать незамысловатый логин и после входа, вывести меню.

Метод `authorisation()`

```
    public void authorisation() {

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Username: ");
            userName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Password: ");
            password = input.nextLine();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < personalList.getPersonalList().size(); i++) {
                if (userName.equals(personalList.getPersonalList().get(i).getUserName()) && password.equals(personalList.getPersonalList().get(i).getPassword())) {
                    startMenu();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Wrong username or\\and password.\n\r" +
                    "Please, type again.\r\r");
        }
    }
```

Метод меню называется `startMenu()`. В этом методе, есть кейс `case 6`, которая должна возвращать пользователся назад к `autorisation()`

```
      case 6:
          authorisation();
          break;
      default:
          System.err.println("Wrong input!");
          break;
```

Когда только запускаешь код, проблем никаких нет, авторизация работает и при правильном вводе username и password выводится меню. Но, после case 6, пропускается первый nextLine и не доходит до цикла. Если между

```
    userName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Password: ");
```

написать `input.nextLine()`, то цикл проверки не запускается, или запускается, но не пропускает дальше.

В чем проблема и как ее решить?

Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nextInt` не считывает конец строки. Добавьте поле него вызов `nextLine()`.